# tpms issues on 2009 jeep liberty

Tags: jeep, tire-pressure-monitoring-system, liberty

Tpms on all 4 tired of my daughter’s 2009 jeep liberty gave been replaced by the tire store but 3 read 0 and one reads - - -  mechanic said it should reset after driving 10-15 minutes and that was 2 days ago. mechanic stated that if it didnt reset, I have two options put old ones back on and full refund or see dealer. please advise

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If the TPMS sensors were replaced (not refurbed with new batteries), they need to be synced with the vehicle. There's a special tool for this. In order for the vehicle to know which sensors belong to it and which position on the vehicle the sensor is at, the vehicle has to be given "introduced" to the new sensor. If not, it won't have a clue and you won't get any readings, which it seems you are experiencing now. You may have to go to a different mechanic or tire shop to get them registered, as it seems the one which changed them out doesn't have a clue.